# android appwidget invalidate

Tags: android, android-appwidget, redraw

I have a home screen widget that tries to mimic a list of items, basically it's just 4 views in a vertical linear layout and there's 2 arrow buttons to "scroll" through list.

I'm able to scroll just fine querying the provider using **limit offset, count**.

The problem is that i'm using a transparent background and when i switch to the next set of results, the text of the item draws over the previous ones. It's like that view doesn't get invalidated.

Has anyone experience something like this? I tried using an opaque background and of course it works but i wanted a transparent one. I tried searching, but haven't found nothing like this.

Thanks,